# Dynamically created checkbox checkedchanged event issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

My issue is that i need to create checkboxes dynamically on a textchanged event of a textbox which are all checked and keeping their checked state count in an int variable assiging it to a label; till here all is successfully done but the problem is now if i uncheck any of the checkboxes i want their count to get decreased by one but the checkchanged event is not firing and by unchecking any of the checkboxes all are gone...
here is my code:

```
        if (DDLType.SelectedItem.Text == "Sick Leave")
            {


                DateTime f = DateTime.Parse(txtFrom.Text);
                DateTime t = DateTime.Parse(txtTo.Text);
                double daydiff = (t - f).TotalDays;

                double p = daydiff;
                for (int i = 1; i <= daydiff; i++)
                {
                    string a = f.ToString("ddd");
                    chklist = new CheckBox();
                    chklist.AutoPostBack = true;
                    chklist.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(CheckChanged);

                    chklist.ID = "chk" + i;
                    chklist.Text = a;
                    chklist.Font.Name = "Trebuchet MS";
                    chklist.Font.Size = 9;
                    chklist.Checked = true;
                    checkcount++;
                    pnlCheck.Controls.Add(chklist);

                    if (a == "Thu" || a == "Fri")
                    {
                        p--;
                        chklist.Checked = false;
                        checkcount--;

                    }
                    f = f.AddDays(1);
                }
                daydiff = p;
                lblCheck.Text = checkcount.ToString();
```

}

```
      protected void CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

        if (!chklist.Checked)
        {
            checkcount--;
            lblCheck.Text = checkcount.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I don't know what is going wrong...

Any help in this regard will highly appreciated 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to make changes to your event handler and check cliked checkbox only.

```
protected void CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        chk = (CheckBox)sender
        if (!chk.Checked)
        {
            checkcount--;
            lblCheck.Text = checkcount.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            checkcount++;
            lblCheck.Text = checkcount.ToString();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. This is because when you send the postback after unchecking a checkbox the remaining checkboxes needs to add dynamically, like you do after the text change event
2. add this to your CheckChanged event: chklist = (CheckBox)sender before the **if** clause

Comment: thanks for the reply, i got your point but i don't know where to recreate the checkboxes after each postback, could you please put more light on it?